# Downloading Files with PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl, qualtrics

I am trying to download a file from an API that I am successfully talking to, however, when I hit the file, it outputs just a bunch of crazy characters. I believe it is the .zip stream, and I just need to get the .csv file that should be in there.

From the API documentation:

```
curl -XGET -H 'X-API-TOKEN: <API TokenZ' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://co1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/SV_50EhstBgHEG2voV/export-responses/2671b6ec-66e0-4e7b-90bc-77174363763d/file -o responses.zip
```

Here is what I have:

```
$file = 'https://co1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/'.$qualtrics_id.'/export-responses/'.$file_json['result']['fileId'].'/file';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $result;

    curl_close ($ch);
```

And this is what it gives me:

```
PKr�JOTest survey.csv�Wmo�����¸�w���W��"��i��M6�m�˂�h����T���3�$+�}{-ĶD93�<3~tܸ+�Dt� ���qW����eQam����� wR+��T̊\����$���(�;��B�]��jeō�[)�{ϭ��o�a�'i���7\V���F��N��*�{�{�����7��:�\I�\�4�cɕU�� �u��"�MS|��It;�ng��<�͢�$�'�g���C$�d9��~���b-T왗�~������mwsu�l�9H�w<�:ڒ������>����J��i�3� �J�~���+�xr��J���W�m�ѰR�V��*X��lYk�޲��Tc9Wl)FRS��B�]��%7����R�zYU��tۭP�T�Y��_��-����v8��VP�K��R� *n�2�ƈu�&����-V� ��y%��� Kh�,���o��e���Y�w���K�.#x�c;]����6��!��уһJƗ�vl+���T��-���A�DTa:P����x�JK��h�y� �t �܈BRLA0K+*� �}�-�AX�\`%`�]+����d,�n�׵g�R��[Y��]� 3�R)��x�?�ۭFjH%��]Ǥ�7����߄p���B"���@p�[����0d�+L���!�������?��x�JoV�Iz"�J���h%��lM�z��ZU![�x�40��$�0hY�0�xST��U�^��G"XT �;�ʞk�����sr�#��� ��F��,4D�v(T6r"w#QI���T;d7㊪^��bW6��pT�B��Q\~`�V�R�/�� ,q�R���\�U�B0ԇ6 ��>ռ�oT�֪|ߖ� � gߍ�x��ĩ����k4$�D�Z�Y���o+�Ƿٞ��d ��K:��r*��O�PXIYB�T�������E5-��������p����S��n�ڳ��$Ptʱ_��቎8��9�S�6��J`��'Q?هJ+X�,� ��@�C�)N���%�����[J`�y���J�"b�?�,� |�JT��ߔ��V���9���c�+��!7��X��}��V�P�nC�9fjվP�|E�0�A��`�}������'��r��H1o��8���ҕ�{�B4� �0>罐i���<�תFp��~��O���L:jEP�N@݈\�@T�4����� ��D����!�_�I<�� ��X��r�SK��MyDG*�h�>�8JM��F���=+��8���8!��e�3�5��K)X|`��3v�� oR���z�}�6������5����gu��5��j��W�I���#b,z���sH�yӜ�c�1����D�uA�:U��b���e�x!�Me>��fH���me�Vn�@d%u�ǔD6C���ynT`a�_��My޳G ���ҹ��͛�n7�HK��e��8�W�E�|״�~���& }�G��T���Jd�!i�^�؂]�4�n�Uc����#�R@��[\��NDDx�� �.4�����i{�:��чw�;��ժۘh`�o��{_y�nE�7���M^Nu����zd*t��h�!}@�9p�����v����_�-�����m��e@��X᧾���� [�����9�m.d����-��l�\�NϮ�+��Yӻ�nO��U7��|~���Xw�����6��Es���dw�<-Z�Ͽ!��8�@��&Z��]�OK��\�����3��3ӳ3��3�3�ٙ$>?�������:?s�����8�fq6�N��$�J�=�C]���F���� �FLY�.F�b��w���Y����״��~���ۏ­����g6�/�%�E<^��ы�q���a2M��?3o����w_q���;y����_��J��h<�b��eI���$�&i2��G���&Ϭ�.������d���I�'���E���t�ݦ�b�_���8ɲy�%q�$x��l����,�������PK��{pnZPKr�JO��{pnZTest survey.csvPK=�
```

I am not sure what to do with this, **I would like to at least be able to download the zip file with the .csv files in there, however, it would be more than ideal to simply get the "Test survey.csv" file**, but I haven't been able to do either, I have tried many different things such as:

```
// header('Content-Type: application/zip');

// readfile($result);

// $z = new ZipArchive();
// $h = $z->getStream( $result );

// stream_get_contents($result);
```

All with no luck, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you put the address of `$file` into a browser are you prompted to download the .csv?

Comment: does it work when you run it in command line?

Comment: @EternalHour No, I put the file into the browser and add the X-API-TOKEN header I get back a super long string in the Response payload. I assume its raw file data, however I am not sure how to encode it or whatever I need to do...

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set `curl_exec` will return downloaded content in the result. So, your variable `$result` actually contains the content of the file (`PKr�`... is a ZIP-header)

So, all you need, just to save the content of the variable in a file, instead of `echo`ing it into the browser.

For example.

```
    ...

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    file_put_contents('downloaded.zip', $result); // save the string to a file

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Good god! I knew it should have been that simple. @AterLux, I needed also to set the RETURNTRANSFER to 0. Thanks!